# Is it OK to delete dialog.**** files from mongodb/data folder

Tags: mongodb

As the title suggests, is it ok to delete the dialog.*** in mongo data folder. This is mainly due to disk space filling up and some files are needed to be cleared. And also if someone can point out which files are not mandatory in the data folder it would be great.

Any tip would be highly appreciated

Comment: you can truncate log file. if you want to clear space, check if any collection can remove or archive.

Comment: No collection can be removed. So in order to clear space its fine to delete the dialog.*** files from the data folder without having an affect to the db right? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I didn't find dialog.*** files in my data directory.